# JS socket.io client doesn't catch an emitted event

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, python-socketio

I'm using a Python based socketio server and JS socketio client. The workflow looks roughly like this:
`client emits <<action1>>` -> `server receives <<action1>>` -> `server performs some calculations` -> `server emits <<action2>>` -> `client receives <<action2>>`
It should work in a loop.

The problem is that for some reason the last step isn't performed, client doesn't seem to catch `action2` event. I can see that it has been fired from the server logs, they state that: `emitting event "action2" to all [/]`

Server:

```
@sio.on('action1')
def handle_analysis():
    ... some calculations ...
    sio.emit('action2')
```

Client:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io("http://localhost:5550",
{
  timeout: 200000
});

  async runCalculations() {
    console.log('progress1');
    let stdoutChunks: string = '';

    const getCalculations = () => {
      socket.emit('action1');   
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          socket.on('action2', (msg) => {
            stdoutChunks += msg;
            resolve(stdoutChunks);
        })
      });
    };
    await getCalculations()
    console.log('progress2');
    return {};
  }
```

`progress2` is never logged, because js keeps on awaiting the `getCalculations` function.
Can anyone point where the issue might be?
Each calculation takes roughly 50 seconds, I wonder if that might be the cause.
I used same approach for different events that take much less time and it works perfectly, server communicates with the client without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good/versed with python-socket.io but isn't *getCalculations()* method defined inside *runCalculations()* in **Client**. So, await *getCalculations()* won't directly work and also in **Server** shouldn't *sio.emit('action2')* also have a second argument like this *sio.emit('action2', 'hello')*. Hope, this may be useful